# change woocommerce product statut (draft ->publish // publish->draft) depends on the month

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, post-status

I have some seasonal products. I thought using "post expirator plugin" but this not managing the "yearly" options. So I thought doing something like this:

```
function saison(){

 $current_month = date('M');
    if(  $current_month == 'Dec' || $current_month == 'Jan' ) {
       wp_update_post( array( 
         'ID' => 789,
         'post_status' => 'publish'
      ));
    } else {
        wp_update_post( array( 
         'ID' => 789,
         'post_status' => 'draft'
      ));
    }
```

}

Someone know how to make something like this in my function.php ?

Answer (score 0):

date('M') => 'Aug' and date('m') => 08

```
add_action('wp', function(){
    $current_month = date('M');
    if( $current_month == 'Aug' ) {
       wp_update_post( array( 
         'ID' => "product_id",
         'post_status' => 'publish'
      ));
    } else {
        wp_update_post( array( 
         'ID' => "product_id",
         'post_status' => 'draft'
      ));
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you :) it's returning no error but my product still published. I've just edit my first post

There is something like "add filter" to add in this function in function.php ?

Comment: I've edited the answer 'wp' action will be fine.

Comment: thanks but still not working :\

Comment: well by making some research, wp_update_post seems not working for woocommerce product since 3.0.... 

If you have another idea....

Comment: If your updates are not working, there could be an error. It is a good idea to set $wp_error to true and display the error immediately after.

Comment: if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
    $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}